# How do i put an event on the marker?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2zrW.png)

```
markerColor: "red",
```

I can change the color in this way.

I'd like to make an event when I click a dot.
I don't know how to approach it, and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can bind [click event](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/click/) to dataPoints (marker/dot) to achieve your requirement. Below is an example:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
    text: "Attaching Click event on dataSeries"
  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "line",
      click: onClick,
      markerColor: "red",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
chart.render();

function onClick(e) {
  alert(  e.dataSeries.type + ", dataPoint { x:" + e.dataPoint.x + ", y: "+ e.dataPoint.y + " }" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```